# Play Console Error 403 after accepting invite

Tags: android, google-play, google-console-developer

I got invitation to publish android app for a team. I am not able to join another developer's group as  it leads to 403 error page when I click accept from the invitation. Does having an own developer account not make you join another google developer account or am I not getting the right permissions from the other group?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like either they have withdrawn the invitation, or you are not signed in with the account the invitation was sent to. I'd ask them to send another invitation to the gmail account you are going to use to accept the invitation.